# How to delete the ~.conda_trash.conda_trash file left over from the Conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda

After I use `conda remove -n env_name -all`, there are still a lot of files ending with `~.conda_trash.conda_trash` that cannot be deleted.

When deleting, the prompt `Operation cannot be completed because the file has been opened in python.` I killed all `python` processes and restarted the computer, but still cannot delete.

The way I do it now is to move them to a temporary folder to save them.

How can I delete these files?